# Kdevelop: Default project filters

Tags: kdevelop

In many of my web development projects I have to exclude the same paths (eg. `node_modules`, `*.min.*`) over and over again. Projects seem to have a default list of exclusions, but so far I have not found a way to edit these. At the moment I add the manually to each and every project.

(Where) can I edit the default list of project filters?